# mulidimensional array in $post simpletest

Tags: php, arrays, simpletest

I want to process an multidimensional array with the $browser->post function simpletest.
I use:

```
$browser->post('someurl/save.html',$array);
```

The array looks like:

```
[mAt[1701]] => Array (
    [0] => 9378
    [1] => 9379
)
```

When I process it it only posts the last value of the array ([1]).
How can I get this to work?

Comment: How do you 'process' your array exactly?

Comment: I want to save a form with the simpletest scriptable browser.
The form contains multiple selectboxes with the same name but different values. When saving the form send an $_POST, I try to replicate this $_POST with simpletest browser. When I manually save the form the $_POST looks like: 

    mAt[1701] = 9378
    mAt[1701] = 9379

I'm trying to do the same with php but I get the values in an multidimensional array which it looks like it can;t be processed by simpletest